# How to remove an element from array in javascript without making a new?

Tags: javascript, html

I read many answers but I didn't understand how to use splice in this case..
Suppose i have an array named alphabets like - ["a","b","c","d","e"] and i have to remove c from it. I dont want to create another array with c removed instead i want to update the same list each time an item is removed just like remove method in python. I know the index also so it can be like alphabets.remove[3]...to remove c. Please help me i am beginner.

Actually it would be better if there's a way that i can remove using just index number cause the names in array are very tough. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Check this [https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To modify the array rather than creating a new one, as you said you'd want the [`splice` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). You pass the index of the item to remove, and the number of items to remove at that index:

```
const index = theArray.indexOf("c");
theArray.splice(index, 1);
```

Live Example:

```js
const theArray = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
const rememberArray = theArray; // Just so we can prove it's the same array later
const index = theArray.indexOf("c");
theArray.splice(index, 1);
console.log(theArray);
console.log("Same array? " + (rememberArray === theArray));
```

Comment: Can you please help once again.. what if the item inside the array is not a string how can i get its index number ?

Comment: @UtkarshTyagi - It doesn't matter what it is, `indexOf` will find it if you pass the same thing into `indexOf`, which effectively does a `===` comparison. Now, if you want to find the index of an object by checking its properties, or a string by a substring, or anything that isn't just a `===` comparison, you'd use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) with a callback (or [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the object itself).

Comment: i have posted a question completely describing my problem It would be really helpful if you would answer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64192200/how-to-remove-an-object-from-array-using-spilce