# How to remove an object from array using spilce?

Tags: javascript, html

I recently asked a question of ([How to remove an element from array in javascript without making a new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64183604/how-to-remove-an-element-from-array-in-javascript-without-making-a-new?noredirect=1#comment113498188_64183604)).

```
b1 = document.getElementById('b1')
b2 = document.getElementById('b2')
myArray = [b1 , b2];
```

Now I have to use this array twice once i need choose random element from it and apply some properties on it and second i need to pop the element i have applied properties. Also its a long list of elements in array so i dont know their index numbers.

For better explanation

```js
blocks = [document.getElementById("b1"),document.getElementById("b2"),document.getElementById("b3"),document.getElementById("b4"),document.getElementById("b5"),document.getElementById("b6"),document.getElementById("b7"),document.getElementById("b8"),document.getElementById("b9")]

//first use
function autoChance(){
    const randomBlock = blocks[Math.floor(Math.random() * blocks.length)];
    randomBlock.style.backgroundColor='blue';
}

//second use
function b1Click(){
    b1.style.backgroundColor="red"
    const index = blocks.indexOf('document.getElementById("b2")');
    blocks.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(blocks)
    autoChance()
}

//If u see in console its removing the last item
```

```css
.blocks{
    width: 310px;
    height: 304px;
    overflow-wrap: normal;
    background-color: aqua;
}
#b1,#b2,#b3,#b4,#b5,#b6,#b7,#b8,#b9{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="blocks">
        <button id="b1" onclick="b1Click()"></button>
        <button id="b2" onclick="b2Click()"></button>
        <button id="b3" onclick="b3Click()"></button>
        <button id="b4" onclick="b4Click()"></button>
        <button id="b5" onclick="b5Click()"></button>
        <button id="b6" onclick="b6Click()"></button>
        <button id="b7" onclick="b7Click()"></button>
        <button id="b8" onclick="b8Click()"></button>
        <button id="b9" onclick="b9Click()"></button>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "using the values"? Please add an actual example.

Comment: I dont know the index number of those object so I want to remove them using their names as shown in example using "c" to first get its index value and then removing it..

Comment: whether it is strings or objects you can use the same syntax to splice

Comment: You can use `findIndex` then splice the array.

Comment: If i use the object name in indexof then it's returning error even if i place it inside double quotes..

Comment: Please add your code together with a [mcve] and the complete error message.

Comment: @UtkarshTyagi That's why you should use `findIndex`, not `indexOf`.

Comment: Ohk let me try..

Comment: This question should show the array of objects you're trying to search, not the code that was solved in the previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my [comment on that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64183604/how-to-remove-an-element-from-array-in-javascript-without-making-a-new/64183623?noredirect=1#comment113512588_64183623), it doesn't matter what it is you're looking for, `indexOf` will find it if you pass the same thing into `indexOf` that's in the array; `indexOf` effectively does a `===` comparison.

Now, if you want to find the index of an object by checking its properties, or a string using a substring, or anything that isn't just a `===` comparison, you'd use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) with a callback (or [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the object itself).

> How can i remove them from array using the values...

The same way: [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) with the index of the entry (if you want to keep the same array) or [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (if you want to create a new array).

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this snippet. When you select elements using methods like `getElementsByTagName`, it may not return array. It might be an HTML collection or some object depending on the method you choose.

As you can see (in console), `initially` is an `object`. To change it to an array, see how I initialized `elements`, using `[...   ]` Rest of the code is easy to understand. Let me know if you get stuck :)

```js
var initially = document.getElementsByTagName('div')

console.log(typeof(initially));

var elements = [...initially];

console.log(elements);

var toSearch = document.querySelector('.four');
var ind = elements.indexOf(toSearch);
elements.splice(ind, 1);

console.log(elements);
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
<div class="five"></div>
<div class="six"></div>
<div class="seven"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would get a random number based on the length of your element array and then splice the array based on that number and return the value from that splice. That value will, however, be in an array so I will need to return the first index of that array.

```js
var myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function removeElement() {
  let randomIndex = randomize(myArray.length);
  let randomValueArr = myArray.splice(randomIndex, 1);
  let randomValue = randomValueArr[0];
  
  console.log(randomValue);
  
  return randomValue;
}

function randomize(max, min = 0) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max + min)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="removeElement()">Click me to remove elements</button>
```